# Getting error while eb deploy : ERROR: NotAuthorizedError - Operation Denied. Access Denied

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

```
ERROR: NotAuthorizedError - Operation Denied. Access Denied
```

Stack:  Django application hosted on AWS using Elasticbeanstalk.

Everything was working fine the last time I deployed using **eb deploy** for my QA environment. Now suddenly getting this error that I'm not authorized to perform this action. Checked the credentials and key-pair as well. Nothing in the settings has been updated after the last deployment. The only thing that is different from the previous deployment is packages since requiremnents.txt has been updated. **eb ssh** is working fine as well.

Update 1:

Gettings these exceptions when tried **eb deploy --debug**

```
raise NotFoundError('Object not found.')
ebcli.objects.exceptions.NotFoundError: Object not found.

raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListMultipartUploads operation: Access Denied

raise NotAuthorizedError('Operation Denied. ' + message)
ebcli.objects.exceptions.NotAuthorizedError: Operation Denied. Access Denied
```

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when your app bundle exceeds a certain application size (in my case, it was about 7 MB, though I'm not sure that'll be universal). When the bundle is over the threshold, Elastic Beanstalk uploads it to S3 along a different code path that needs different permissions (it calls the `ListMultipartUploads` API call, where previously it called `put_object`). **Add `S3FullAccess` permission to the deployment user to solve it.**

Here's the relevant part of `eb deploy --verbose` output when you're *under* the threshold (i.e. before you encounter this problem):

```
2023-10-04 12:49:58,864 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.s3 : Upload Application Version. File size = 7339817
Uploading Staging2/app-94dee-231004_124957202923.zip to S3. This may take a while.

2023-10-04 12:49:58,864 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.aws : Making api call: (s3, put_object) to region: us-east-1 with args:{'Bucket': 'elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1-082424411102', 'Key': 'Staging2/app-94dee-231004_124957202923.zip', 'Body': <_io.BufferedReader name='/Users/michaelkeenan/Programming/projects/ForumMagnum2/.elasticbeanstalk/app_versions/app-94dee-231004_124957202923.zip'>}

2023-10-04 12:50:09,246 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.aws : API call finished, status = 200
```

Here's the relevant part when you exceed the threshold, and deployment now fails with an improbable-seeming error about authorization, when it worked fine yesterday and you haven't changed any permissions config:

```
2023-10-04 12:23:54,306 (DEBUG) Upload Application Version. File size = 7340290

2023-10-04 12:23:54,306 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.s3 : Doing multi-threaded upload. Parts Needed=2

2023-10-04 12:23:54,306 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.aws : Making api call: (s3, list_multipart_uploads) to region: us-east-1 with args:{'Bucket': 'elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1-082424411102', 'Prefix': 'Staging2/app-e7ece-231004_122352172258.zip'}

2023-10-04 12:23:54,385 (DEBUG) ebcli.lib.aws : Response: {'Error': {'Code': 'AccessDenied', 'Message': 'Access Denied'}, 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'F60N3HS7SNHWEN27', 'HostId': 'UTvqboW3F6Nfl+24iGPMgCGka3OBP3/nY8s+WqDG8enzCoKSTg2eo/FDLqiPn2QqFdrH7DNWWZI=', 'HTTPStatusCode': 403, 'date': 'Wed, 04 Oct 2023 19:23:53 GMT', 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

It made an S3 `put_object` API call (successfully) in the working case, but when the bundle was just slightly bigger, it tried an S3 `list_multipart_uploads` API call (unsuccessfully). It seems you can have `put_object` permission but not `list_multipart_uploads` permission.