# AWS EB throws operation denied error when init new app

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I found an [example](https://gist.github.com/hassy/48bae515c393e9214d3f) how to push Parse server to AWS.

but when do `eb init` and set the name for the app I want to create

it throws next error:

```
ERROR: NotAuthorizedError - Operation Denied. User: arn:aws:iam::547822629163:user/Oleksandr is not authorized to perform: elasticbeanstalk:CreateApplication on resource: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:eu-west-3:547822629163:application/parse-server-test
```

I've added a user on amazon with this permissions and created access key and sectet for this user:

[image]

Comment: The AdminAccess-EB Role you're using contains the permissions to do `elasticbeanstalk:*` on any resource, it must be something down the line (or you're not using the right credentials). Have you tried with the `--debug` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/76281413/995891) or `--verbose` flags (https://stackoverflow.com/a/77232660/995891)? Worst case: change access to the full "AdministratorAccess" which isn't restricted at all.

Comment: thanks full access works perfect I will debug the issue also